# Contact Form Undefined Method Error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create a contact form that will email directly to a gmail account.

For this I have used this tutorial: [Contact Form for Rails](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/)

The issue I am having is that it is throwing up the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I have literally followed this tutorial to the letter and so the code can all be seen on the link above.

Any advise would really be much appreciated! Thanks

**Update with full error**

NoMethodError in Contact#new

```
 Showing C:/Sites/jobapp_v2/app/views/contact/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:

   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

  Extracted source (around line #1):

   1: <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
   2:   <fieldset class="fields">
   3:   <div class="field">
   4:     <%= form.label :name %>

   Rails.root: C:/Sites/jobapp_v2
```

Comment: In which line and class the error is shown?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated my question with the full error. Let me know if I can provide more information

Comment: I guess it should be `contacts_path` instead of `contact_path`.

Comment: That's what I think too @Kulbir Saini. You should make that an answer.

Comment: Hey, I have tried contacts_path but this causes another undefined method error `undefined local variable or method `contacts_path'`. Any other ideas? :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

delete the routes you have for contact, and replace them with this:

```
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```